# Running a makefile using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, find

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
.
├── one
│   ├── one_one
│   │   └── one_one_one
│   │       ├── Makefile
│   │       └── one_one_oneTest.cpp
│   └── one_two
│       ├── Makefile
│       └── one_twoTest.cpp
├── three
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── threeTest.cpp
└── two
    └── two_one
        ├── Makefile
        └── two_oneTest.cpp
```

I want to run the make command where ever I find the Makefile. So, I have written a shell script as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -name Makefile -exec make \;
```

But it gives error saying `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`

If I just run `find . -type f -name Makefile`, I get

```
./two/two_one/Makefile
./three/Makefile
./one/one_two/Makefile
./one/one_one/one_one_one/Makefile
```

which is the correct output I expected.

If I run the Makefile using make command, it runs properly, so I think the Makefile is correct.
What can be wrong with the shell script?

Just for reference, one of my Makefiles is as follows:

```
all: TestTwoOne

TestTwoOne: two_oneTest.cpp
    g++ two_oneTest.cpp -o TestTwoOne
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "current directory" is not being changed to the appropriate subdirectories for running the make. Do this instead:

```
find . -type f -name Makefile -execdir make \;
```